# Trigger Action by Focusing on URL Bar

Tags: javascript, url, browser

I want to be able to use JavaScript to trigger an action (for example, display an alert pop-up) when a user clicks in the browser URL bar.

The goal is to let a user know that if they navigate away from the page by typing a new URL, possible changes they've made will not be saved.

Is this possible, and if yes, how can this be done?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

While there is no way to determine if the user has clicked on the address bar, you can use certain JS events to still prompt the user if a change has been made.  The javascript event you want to look at is [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload).

What I've typically done in the past is set a couple of variables.  One to check if the page has changed and potentially needs to be saved, and another to check if they are navigating away from the page via a proper method (i.e. a control on my page) or just simply navigating away (i.e. the URL bar).  If both of the conditions are met, then you can prompt the user they may lose changes.